# Center a fixed background image that is in a centered div while using Parallax effect

Tags: jquery, css, html, parallax

**Note:** I have uploaded the page onto my site so hopefully it will be easier to solve:

http://www.jasonkahl.co.uk/div-center/index.html

I am working on a small website that uses the Parallax effect.

However I wanted my first image which is a background image in a div to always be in the center of the screen when the user goes on. So I used the following script to center the DIV which is called **#second .bg**:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function CenterItem(theItem){
    var winHeight=$(window).height();
    var windowMiddle=winHeight/2;
    var itemMiddle=$(theItem).height()/2;
    var theMiddle=windowMiddle-itemMiddle;
    if(winHeight>$(theItem).height()){ //vertical
        $(theItem).css('top',theMiddle);
    } else {
        $(theItem).css('top','0');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    CenterItem('#second .bg');
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    CenterItem('#second .bg');
});

</script>
```

The DIV itself is centering but the background image does not and ends up looking like so (note: the blue box is the div position):

[image]

and this is what happens when the script is removed:

[image]

So how do I get the background image to be in the center of the DIV?

if it helps here is how the div is set up in the html:

```
<div id="second">
      <div class="story"><div class="bg"></div>
      </div> <!--.story-->      
</div> <!--#second-->
```

and here is the CSS:

```
#second .bg{
    background: url(images/logo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed ;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: forgot to mention - parallax code was from here:

http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/

Comment: You can edit your question when you need to add more info. `=]` Also it'd be much easier to debug with either a link to the page or a http://jsfiddle.net too.

Comment: Thank you Fabricio for your advice - I am now hosting the page so you can see it. Its at the top of my question  :)